# Sending email using SES node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to send email to my other email from amazon SES verified email, but the programs gives an error that email address in to field is not verified. I am making a web app which allows user to log in using AWS Cognito so I dont have their email addresses in database. I need to send email to them on an event(I cannot use SNS because I need to send emails to selective persons which I have figured out.) So my questions are:
a)Do we need to verify SES email of the recipient also?
b)If yes, how can we use the cognito identity pool to verify their email addresses for SES.

code:

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
aws.config.update({
    region: "us-west-2",
});

var ses = new aws.SES({"accessKeyId": "Mykey", "secretAccessKey":"YY","region":"us-west-2"})



var to = ['xyz@gmail.com']
var from='abc@gmail.com'




ses.sendEmail( {
    Source: from,
    Destination: { ToAddresses: to },
    Message: {
            Subject:{
    Data:"Sending emails through SES"
},
        Body: {
    Text: {
        Data: 'Stop your messing around',
    }
}
}
}
, function(err, data) {
    if(err) throw err
    console.log('Email sent:');
    console.log(data);
}
```

Error:

MessageRejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2:  xyz@gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

If you're testing this inside your SES sandbox, you need to manually verify the recipient email addresses before it will allow you to send.

This step isn't required after leaving the sandbox, but it's a reasonable default safety setting when testing email-related functionality during development and not wanting bogus emails to go our for real.

[Amazon SES Email Sending Errors](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/ses-errors.html) (relevant portion in bold):

> Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the
>   check in region : , , —You
>   are trying to send email from an email address or domain that you have
>   not verified with Amazon SES. This error could apply to the "From",
>   "Source", "Sender", or "Return-Path" address. **If your account is still
>   in the sandbox, you also must verify every recipient email address**

An easier way to test your email sending in AWS without needing to send actual emails would be to use their [mailbox simulator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mailbox-simulator.html):

> The Amazon SES mailbox simulator is a set of test email addresses.
>   Each email address represents a specific scenario. You can send emails
>   to the mailbox simulator when you want to:
>
> Test your application without having to create test "To" addresses.

Comment: Very detailed answer!! Nice one!